# Specific Thumbnail Size for Custom Content Type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

Is there any solution for setting specific thumbnail size for any custom content type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the quickest way to do that is:

1. Add your specific thumbnail size to functions.php. [Here's the code to do it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Add_New_Post_Thumbnail_Sizes).
2. Find the specific template file in your theme that displays your custom content type, then modify it to display your recently added thumbnail size. [Use the following code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails#Thumbnail_Sizes), enter the specific thumbnail id you added in point 1 as the parameter.
3. Additionally, you can use the **AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild** plugin so WordPress create thumbnails in your specific size. This is especially useful if you already have a running site with plenty of thumbnails in place.